# pipe() from 1 parent to multiple child processes in separate c file

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe, fork

I have a program that creates multiple child processes using `fork()`. The program starts in main of parent.c. After forking, the parent calls `excel` to execute child.c. How exactly do I share a pipe between the two different programs. I know I would have to create a pipe in parent.c for each child process like this:

```
int myPipe[nChildren][2];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < nChildren; i++) {
    if (pipe(myPipe[i]) == -1) {
        perror("pipe error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(pipe[i][0]); // parent does not need to read
}
```

But what do I need to do in child.c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child process needs to communicate the pipe FD to the `execl`'ed program. The easiest way is to use `dup2` to move the pipe to FD 0 (`stdin`). 
For example:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  // in child
  dup2(pipe[i][0], 0);
  execl(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a command-line argument in child.c to accept the FD number of the pipe. for example:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  // in child
  sprintf(pipenum, "%d", pipe[i][0]);
  execl("child", "child", pipenum, (char *) NULL);
}
```

The child program would need to use `atoi` or `strtoul` to convert `argv[1]` to an integer and then use that as the input FD.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `dup2`. Can you please show an example of passing the FD number? Thanks

Comment: But I'm not allowed to use `dup2.` Since the child only needs to read, do I just pass `pipe[0]` as the command line argument?